# How to resize Yahoo Messenger window?

Tags: user-interface, accessibility, yahoo-messenger

Yahoo Messenger is **huge**:

[image]

And that's as short as you can make it, it won't shrink vertically anymore.

How can I make it a more reasonable size, e.g.:

[image]

In fact, if we're making it look better, how about Yahoo stops not caring about their users and makes it:

[image]

Okay, yes, the last one was me complaining. But the first two are a valid question!

**Note:** The cut-off title bar is because Yahoo! developers [don't pay their taxes](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2005/08/22/454487.aspx), and assume that everyone runs at 96dpi.

Comment: Not an answer, but if you can live without all the ads you should give pidgin a try. http://www.pidgin.im/download/windows/

Comment: or Trillian, free edition...works well with many IM services, including Yahoo!.  includes Facebook, Windows Live, AOL, etc...http://www.trillian.im/

Comment: might want to blur parts of your screenshots, they are displaying your email...just a suggestion...

Comment: @studiohack i did obscure my e-mail address. And by obscuring it, i changed it. i guess you don't know who Joel Splosky is. And my subtle joke fails.

Comment: @honk, @studiohack: i use Y!, not because it's a good product, but because it's the only product that can send SMS (i.e. text messages) for free. (Live Messenger gives an error message with the person i want to message, Skype requires credits)

Comment: @Ian Boyd: no, I don't know who Joel Splosky is but I did wonder about it being a Gmail address...and yes, I actually SMS from Y! myself...sometimes it doesn't deliver all the text messages though...ever have that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still using the old 8.1.0.421 version because I have no need for the extra stuff they put into the latest versions but this is how my window looks:

[image: clean YM window]

I do not know to which extent this can still be done in newer versions, but the way I did it on the version that I'm using was by going to the "Messenger" menu >> Show/Hide >> Unchecked everything but "Status Chooser" (for an even more compact view, this can be unchecked as well). Basically, a lot of stuff can be either disabled or hidden to make the most compact view possible.

For the annoying ads (I mean, seriously, forcing animated, flashy ads on a user's desktop ?!), I used a batch script ([noYMads](http://ionutalexchitu.googlepages.com/noYMads2.bat)) that does the required modifications automatically, but for your version, doing a quick search on Google will give you plenty of options. One that popped out and looked promising is [Ad Banner Remover Plus](http://www.wackyb.com/vb/showthread.php?p=72001).

Also, just in case you're interested in this older version, it can still be found on  [oldversion.com](http://www.oldversion.com).

Comment: +1 for oldversion.com - i didn't know about that i got version 8 of Ygly. It still had ads, doesn't support high-dpi mode (so everything is impossibly tiny to read), and it doesn't allow resizing. But it is a little bit shorter. So that's good.

Comment: Just in case anyone is interested in that batch script I mentioned which works on the old version of YM, I have edited my answer and added a link to it as well.